# PHP HTML MySQL for offline solution

Tags: php, html, mysql, offline

I am trying to develop a website using PHP and MySQL that support for offline.

My requirement would be:

- when internet is down, user able to use the browser and browse to my
  full website and doing normal operation.
  2
- By doing normal operation, it means user are able to perform normal CRUD functionality.
- CRUD work with mysql, which when internet is down, mysql is still running locally and when internet is back, there will be a sync
  process to sync local mysql into server db.

Any suggestion of solution or links to the solution for this is much appreciated.

Comment: Closed as "off topic" in 5, 4, 3 ...

Comment: If you have a control over the live server, take a look at MySQL Replication

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-configuration.html

Comment: Good luck with that. Does it happen that often that a users internet is down? Could you not just check for the internet connection and display a message to the user?

Comment: i will check on that link. It is not as simple as you think @putvande. It doesn't happen often but it needs to be handled when it happens. Even small detail that doesn't happen often, we still need to fix.

Answer (score -2):

Off topic, but look at the HTML5 Web Storage API (specifically local storage). There are many tutorials explaining how it can be used for offline web apps.

Comment: Not sure what the down vote is for?? This is a perfectly valid solution to offline web apps.